# How to add an array of a specific length using mongoose.Schema in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm working on a project and need an array value, when entered, to have an array length of at least 12. I've read through some of the documentation on their site and I haven't found anything yet so I thought it wouldn't hurt to post here while I continue searching.

This is an example of the code.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
Array: {
         type: Array,
         required: true,
       }
});
```

Any insights you have would be greatly appreciated! If there's something I could clarify better please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`validate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) from mongoose while defining your schema.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
Array: {
         type: Array,
         required: true,
         validate : lengthMin12
       }
});


const lengthMin12 = (val) => {
return val.length >= 12;
}
```

PS : The above link is from the latest version, but validate is available for older mongoose versions too.